# Is the reaction force exerted by an accelerated body less than the applied force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

If I exert a force $F$ on an object and it is moving with an acceleration $a$, does it exert the same force $F$ or a lesser force?

Comment: The same force F, on you.

Comment: Please can you provide more explanation. Why do you think Newton's 3rd Law does not apply in this situation?